# How to get currently opened workspace folder path in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have opened many project in visual studio code.I am trying to get currently opened workspace folder path in VS code extension but not getting.

```
vscode.workspace.workspaceFolder[0].uri.fsPath;
```

VS Code folder structure:

```
projects - main folder

   project1       - my project folder
     -node_modules
     -src

   project2       - my project folder
     -node_modules
     -src

   project3       - my project folder
     -node_modules
     -src
```

I have opened one file from src folder project3. Now I want to get my workspace folder like c://mamp/htdocs/projects/project3  but instead of this I am getting c://mamp/htdocs/projects So How do resolve this?